# Python: Output of the elements of the list as separate lists, how to put them all in a unique list?

Tags: python, list, printing, output

This is my code, the program is doing it's job but I don't understand why I don't get one unique list when I print.
Why do I get each number as a separate list?

The code is easy to understand.

I have no clue how I could fit all my values in one list cz I actually don't even understand why I'm getting them in separate lists, even when I append them as integers and not as strings.
Anyone could enlighten me a bit?

Thank you for your help,

Rouba

```
#################################
# Ex1: Nombres de Amstrong
# 20205793 
# Créé le 14/03/2021
################################

for a in range(100):
    for b in range(100):
        for c in range(100):
```

#takes all the numbers from 0 to 99

```
nb = int(str(a)+str(b)+str(c))
```

#sums up the numbers as characters

```
sommeCubes=a**3+b**3+c**3
```

#sums up the numbers to the power 3 for each

```
liste=[]
```

#creation of an empty list

```
if nb==sommeCubes:
```

`I tried liste.append(nb)`

```
                liste.append(str(nb))
                        print(liste)
```

#add to the list the numbers of which  the sum of its numbers to the power 3 is equivalent to the number as a string

Output:

```
['0']
['1']
['153']
['2213']
['370']
['371']
['407']
['4160']
['4161']
['41833']
['1000']
['1001']
['165033']
['221859']
['341067']
['444664']
['487215']
['982827']
['983221']
[Finished in 1.8s]
```

Comment: you create an empty list in every iteration. Create the list before the loops. And then print the end result after the loop end, not inside the loop.

Comment: Oh that's true, tt's so obvious. I'm still new to all that. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
liste=[]
for a in range(100):
    for b in range(100):
        for c in range(100):
            nb = int(str(a)+str(b)+str(c))
            sommeCubes=a**3+b**3+c**3                
            if nb==sommeCubes: liste.append(str(nb))

print(liste)
```

**Output :**

```
['0', '1', '153', '2213', '370', '371', '407', '4160', '4161', '41833', '1000', '1001', '165033', '221859', '341067', '444664', '487215', '982827', '9
83221']
```

You need to initialise your list outside the loop.

Comment: Yea you're right and I need to put the print outside the if statement otherwise I will get multiple lists. I'm starting to understand the logic behind all the indentations and the order of the lines of code. Thank you for ur help!!

Comment: You're welcome :) Indentation is very important in Python!

Comment: That's true, it affects a lot the function of the program